# Memory error in networkx using large dataset

Tags: python, list, memory, networkx, graph-theory

I create a directed graph with `networkx` using a large text dataset. Then I used the function simple_cycles( `cycles = nx.simple_cycles(G))` ) to find all the cycles in the graph but I get a memory error because this function returns a huge list. Is there any other way to find the cycles of the directed graph?

Comment: You ask for all cycles and complain about the number of cycles returned? Did you check the theory about how many cycles are to be expected?

Comment: The problem is that i dont get the cycles because of a memory error. The list is huge and there is not enough memory. Im asking if there is another way to take all the cycles without getting memory error. Im also expecting many cycles because the graph is huge